# Javascript scroll will no work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Her my simple JS code in the head of my XSLT page:

```
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var scrollTo = $('#what').get(0);
    scrollTo.scrollIntoView();
    alert(scrollTo.innerHTML);
</script>
```

The div Element with the id = "what" is at the bottom of the page. It will not scroll there when I open the page. Why not?

Comment: Ah one more! `Java != Javascript`, its there in the wiki of Javascript tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: -1 for not reading the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

Comment: Worked great thanks so much. If I have a table in a div with overflow can i scroll inside the div to certain table row as well?

Comment: `$('#divID').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#tableRowID').offset().top
    }, 'slow');`

Comment: Great thanks! Will this work if the rows don´t have ids and i need to use the row numbers?:                                           $('#divID').animate({ scrollTop:  $('#tableid').find('tr').eq(line ).offset().top }, 'slow');

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have never tried like that. I usually do it using the _ID_ but you go give it a try...